# Broken links in wordpress due to .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, url, 404, broken-links

I was playing around with the .htaccess file on my site, and though the homepage works. All links are broken, showing 404 error. I also cannot click on anything but the homepage.

If it matters here is the .htaccess

```
RewriteOptions inherit
# BEGIN LSCACHE
# END LSCACHE
# BEGIN NON_LSCACHE
# END NON_LSCACHE

#User added redirects
redirect 301 ^/channelactivist\.com/?(.*) http://channelactivist.com/$1 
redirect 301 people-of-earth-unrenewed-at-tbs/      http://channelactivist.com/people-of-earth-unrenewed-at-tbs/ (#500+ of these)

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: I know you know this now and sorry to be pedantic, but just make sure you make a backup copy of any file before editing. I forgot this sooooo many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax errors in the 2 redirects you have listed.

"Redirect" does not allow `^` or `\` or `?(.*)`. You need to use "RedirectMatch":

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/channelactivist\.com/?(.*) http://channelactivist.com/$1
```

For the other lines, you need an opening `/` or it won't match those URLs. It's also more common to use a space instead of a tab. However, this redirect actually doesn't redirect at all - you're pointing the same URL at itself (unless this .htaccess is on a site other than channelactivist.com), so hopefully your actual redirects are a little different than what you posted:

```
Redirect 301 /people-of-earth-unrenewed-at-tbs/ http://channelactivist.com/people-of-earth-unrenewed-at-tbs/
```

You can verify these are the problem by removing your redirects and adding one at a time, then testing and tweaking to make sure it works, before adding the others.

Comment: Thank you. I managed to fix the 404 errors on the links within the site. Turns out the .htaccess page was corrupt. I'm going to work on adding that / to the other links on the site.